# Rearranging by Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
A = [a 2 5 8;
     b 4 8 NaN]
```

where `a` and `b` are `1x3` row vectors.

I need to get a cell array `B` with:

```
B{1}=2 a
B{2}=5 a
B{3}=8 a b
B{4}=4 b
```

The ordering doesn't matter though.

So I need to put the 4,5,6..th columns element by element with respect to those `1x3` row vectors `a` and `b`, disregarding `NaN`.

My first try was `unique(A)`, but this alone couldn't eliminate `NaN`, nor can it match correctly.

Perhaps I also need to get the index matrix of at which "row" each element (2,5,8,4,8,), but I couldn't find how.

I then tried using `for` and `if`. But my PC was unable to process this with huge file size.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a matrix `A`:

```
A = [a 2 5 8;
     b 4 8 NaN];
```

I'll first split the matrix into parts consisting of `a` and `b` and the rest:

```
a_and_b = A(:,1:3);
Arest = A(:,4:end);
```

then we'll see what the unique items are in this `Arest` matrix, and remove the `NaN`s:

```
Arest_uniq = unique(Arest);
Arest_uniq = Arest_uniq(~isnan(Arest_uniq));
```

check the occurences of the elements in `Arest_uniq` in rows of `Arest`:

```
occur_A = arrayfun(@(ii) ismember(Arest_uniq,Arest(ii,:)),1:size(A,1),'uni',false);
```

Because adding those rows `a` and/or `b` based on an if-construction isn't a linear operation, I'd rather just do it in a loop.

```
output = num2cell(Arest_uniq);
for ii=1:numel(output)
    for jj=1:size(A,1)
        if occur_A{jj}(ii)
            output{ii} = [output{ii} a_and_b(jj,:)];
        end
    end
end
```

Go through this with [step-by-step debugging](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-192), inspect variables on the way, and eventually you'll understand what everything does. So next time you can solve your problems yourself on the spot.

Comment: @Gunther_Struyf Thanks. But can you make it without using for and if ? I mean some simple and elegant method.

Comment: this _is_ a simple and elegant method, there is no objection against a for-loop in this case imo, especially with matlab's JIT compiler.