# Matlab column to row while matching original row

Tags: matlab

There are no duplicates in `A(:,2:end)`

I want to put the elements of `A(:,2:end)` to `B(:,2)` and the corresponding `A(:,1)` into `B(:1)` disregarding NaN.

```
A = [2 3 5;
     1 9 NaN]


B = [2 3;
     2 5;
     1 9]
```

`B(:,2)` can be made by `unique(A(:,2:end))` and by putting `B(ismember(B(:,2),NaN),:)=[]`

But How to do matching part?

Comment: Why do you need to use `unique` to create `B(:,2)` given that you state that "there are no duplicates in `A(:,2:end)`"? Surely you could just use `V = A(:,2:end)`, `V = V(:)`, and then `V = V(~isnan(V))`? That should be a lot faster than calling `unique`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a second solution (assuming I've interpreted the question correctly):

```
%// Build column 1
BCol1 = kron(A(:, 1), ones(size(A, 2) - 1, 1));

%// Build column 2
BCol2 = A(:, 2:end)';
BCol2 = BCol2(:);

%// Get an index of nans and remove them to obtain solution
I1 = ~isnan(BCol2);
B = [BCol1(I1), BCol2(I1)];
```

I looped 1000 times over my solution versus that of @EitanT for an input matrix of size 100x100, results are:

```
Elapsed time is 0.299024 seconds. %// My solution
Elapsed time is 0.434274 seconds. %// @EitanT solution
```

Note, I've assumed here that the first column of `A` won't contain any `nan`. An adjustment to take this into account shouldn't be too difficult, although you'll have to provide some more information about how you would want the rest of the row to be treated.

Comment: @Colin_T_Bowers Very interesting. kron is useful. Actually I also had a similar question when there are duplicates in the columns. In that case I wanted to put them in same line for duplicates like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916164/rearranging-by-matlab    The only answerer had to rely on for and if. But I am trying to find a non-loop solution.

Comment: @Colin_T_Bowers So to solve that question by using your answer, I created another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964259/marge-2-to-end-columns-for-duplicates-in-1st-column   If this question is solved, then, I can use the answers in 17940788 and 17964259 to solve 17916164. Do you think this will be also possible?

Comment: @user2604484 It isn't immediately obvious to me how to solve those problems without loops, and I'm afraid it could be some time before I have a decent size chunk of spare time (yesterday was a rarity for me at the moment :-). Also, GuntherStruyf and Dan are both very good Matlab coders, so I'm guessing it will be tough to find something cleverer than what they've done. But nonetheless, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized solution:

```
[Y, X] = find(true(size(A, 1), size(A, 2) - 1));
B = [A(X(:), 1), reshape(A(:, 2:end), [], 1)];
B(any(isnan(B), 2), :) = []; %// Remove NaN values
```