# Merge 2nd to last columns for duplicates in 1st column

Tags: matlab

I want to merge A's 2nd to end column if A's 1st column is duplicate

From

```
A = [2 3 1;
     3 4 2;
     2 6 8]
```

to

```
B{1}=2 3 1 6   8
B{2}=3 4 2 NaN NaN
```

or

```
B = [2 3 1 6    8;
     3 4 2 NaN NaN]
```

row ordering doesn't matter.

My first plan was

```
A=sortrows(A,1); % sort by 1st col
```

and then divide A into various matrices according to 1st col (i.e. different matrix for different 1st column element)

then horzcat each 2:end elements for each matrices.

and then join them into one object in some way.

This is simply my plan or imagination though I can't figure out if this is possible.

Comment: related question: [Group values in different rows by their first-column index](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17447474/1336150)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to get you started. It will pad with `0` instead of `NaN` though:

```
B = sortrows(A,1);
C = B(1,:);    

for row = 2:size(B,1)
    if B(row,1) == C(end,1)
        C(end, end+1:end+2) = B(row, 2:3);
    else
        C(end+1, 1:3) = B(row, :);
    end
end
```

Or you could do the same thing using a cell array and not have to pad at all:

```
B = sortrows(A,1);
C = {B(1,:)};    

for row = 2:size(B,1)
    if B(row,1) == C{end}(1)
        C{end}(end+1:end+2) = B(row, 2:3);
    else
        C{end+1} = B(row, :);
    end
end
```